# Publishing site and left menu

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

In Sharepoint 2010 I have a publishing site and when ever I create a new page I want the new page to appear as a menu item in the left menu.

Something like this:

Department 1

- Page 1
- Page 2

Can I please have some pointers?

Thanks :)

Comment: You can follow this blog article to correct it: http://geekswithblogs.net/naijacoder/archive/2007/09/23/115552.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is a default behavior of SharePoint 2010's publish site.
If you can't see the newly created page's link shown at the left panel, you can goto "Site Actions-->Site Settings-->Look and Feel-->Navigation-->Current Navigation" and make sure that you have the option "Show Pages" checked.